# How can I monitor XML parsing in Java (with JDOM)?

Tags: java, jdom

I'm developing an app that parses big XML files (over 200k lines, about 4-5 MB), and I would like to monitor the parsing using a progress bar.
I'm using JDOM v1.1.1 and SaxBuilder.

Anyone knows how to achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could, I suppose, subclass `org.jdom.DefaultJDOMFactory`, and override some of the methods to track when certain nodes get created. You can then pass an object of that subclass to the `SAXBuilder.setFactory`.

It's be up to you to decide what constitutes "progress", though, which you'll only be able to decide based on the structure of the XML.

Comment: Given that my XML always comes from a file, can't I check the read byte count, and compare it to the total byte count ?

Comment: @Squ36: If you want to get low-level, you'll have to provide your your own SAX implementation, and pass it to the constructor of `SAXBuilder`.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the exact same (thank you Stackoverflow! :)).
@Squ36, were you able to do something in the end?